# my while statement wont print to my output file

Tags: c++

My `while` statement won't print to my output file. Not sure why.

This up here was just the start:

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    
    string inFileName;
    string outFileName;
    char inputFileNumber;


    ifstream fin;

    ofstream fout;

    
    //Output the divider to the screen
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(SCREEN_WIDTH + 1) << " " << setfill(' ') << endl;

    //Calculate the centering print width
    //Output the centered college heading to the screen
    //Calculate the centering print width
    //Output the centered course heading to the screen
    //Calculate the centering print width
    //Output the centered lab name to the screen
    //Calculate the centering print width
    //Output the centered programmer's name to the screen
    //Output the divider to the screen

    cout << setw((SCREEN_WIDTH + COLLEGE.length()) / 2) << COLLEGE << endl;
    cout << setw((SCREEN_WIDTH + COURSE.length()) / 2) << COURSE << endl;
    cout << setw((SCREEN_WIDTH + LAB_NAME.length()) / 2) << LAB_NAME << endl;
    cout << setw((SCREEN_WIDTH + PROGRAMMER_NAME.length()) / 2) << PROGRAMMER_NAME << endl;
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(SCREEN_WIDTH + 1) << " " << setfill(' ') << endl;


    // Task 0
    // Output file options on the screen
    // Input the file number from the keyboard
    // Determine the input & output files to open & output the file names and opening message to 
    //  the screen based on the file number
    // Set the formatting for the output file

    

    cout << "Select the input file :" << endl;
    cout << "1. Lab5In-1.txt" << endl;
    cout << "2. Lab5In-2.txt" << endl; 

    cout << ('\n'); 
    cout << ('\n');

    cout << "Enter the number of the input files : ";
    cin >> inputFileNumber;

    if (inputFileNumber == '1' )
    {
        cout << "The input file Lab5In-1.txt is successfully opend." << endl;
        cout << "The output file Lab5Out-1.txt is sucessfully opened." << endl;
        fin.open("Lab5In-1.txt");
        fout.open("Lab5Out-1.txt");


    }
    else if (inputFileNumber == '2')
    {
        cout << "The input file Lab5In-2.txt is successfully opend." << endl;
        cout << "The output file Lab5Out-2.txt is sucessfully opened." << endl;
        fin.open("Lab5In-2.txt");
        fout.open("Lab5Out-2.txt");
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Output the course heading to the output file
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // print course heading in output file 
    fout << setfill('-') << setw(SCREEN_WIDTH + 1) << " " << setfill(' ') << endl;
    fout << setw((SCREEN_WIDTH + COLLEGE.length()) / 2) << COLLEGE << endl;
    fout << setw((SCREEN_WIDTH + COURSE.length()) / 2) << COURSE << endl;
    fout << setw((SCREEN_WIDTH + LAB_NAME.length()) / 2) << LAB_NAME << endl;
    fout << setw((SCREEN_WIDTH + PROGRAMMER_NAME.length()) / 2) << PROGRAMMER_NAME << endl;
    fout << setfill('-') << setw(SCREEN_WIDTH + 1) << " " << setfill(' ') << endl;
```

This is take one where the task 1 program starts and it wont print the information:

```cpp
    // Task 1 - Tuition Discount 
    cout << ('\n');
    cout << ('\n');
    cout << ('\n');

    // Output the task heading to the output file

    fout << "Task 1 - tuition Discount" << endl;
just adding more details so I can post I appolgize in advance !
    getline(fin, studentName);
## THE PROBLEM STARTS HERE!!
    while (fin)
    {
        fin >> studentName;
        fin >> semestersCompleted;
        fin >> gpa;

        // Initialize student's semster discount
        semesterDiscount = 0;


        // Initialize student's GPA discount 
        gpaDiscount = 0;

        totalDiscount = SEMESTER_AMOUNT + GPA_AMOUNT;

        if (semestersCompleted >= 3)
        {
            fout << "Name : " << studentName << endl;
            fout << "Semesters Completed : " << semestersCompleted << endl;
            fout << "GPA" << gpa << endl;

            fout << setfill('-') << setw(SCREEN_WIDTH + 1) << " " << setfill(' ') << endl;

            fout << "Semester Discount : " << SEMESTER_AMOUNT << endl;
            fout << "GPA Discount : " << GPA_AMOUNT << endl;
            fout << "Total Discount : " << totalDiscount << endl;
        }

            


        fin.ignore(100, '\n');

        getline(fin, studentName);

        //Close the input & output files
        fin.close();
        fout.close();
    }
```

Comment: Please shorten this down to the very minimum of lines of code necessary to reproduce the problem. Make it a [mcve]. Don't remove things needed to be able to compile it - and don't include things not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is `semestersCompleted >= 3` ever equal to `true`?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually opening `fout`? It doesn't open in `fileNumber` isn't one of the correct values.

Comment: Your loop is closing `fin` and `fout` after the 1st iteration, so why do you have a loop at all? I think you need to get rid of the `close`'s, and change `getline(fin, studentName); while (fin) { ... getline(fin, studentName); }` to `while (getline(fin, studentName)) { ... }`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you write code, start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then build up. First write code that reads one `studentName` and prints it to the screen. Once that works, read and print the other two variables as well. Once that works, write a while loop that goes through the whole input file. (Getting that to work will probably force you to correct the loop and the double-reading of `studentName`.) Then try writing a single `studentName` to the output file, and proceed from there.

Comment: `cout << "The input file Lab5In-2.txt is successfully opend." << endl;` maybe you should only print this message if it is true. I mean `if (fin.open("Lab5In-2.txt")) cout << "The input file Lab5In-2.txt is successfully opend." << endl; else cout << "The input file could not be opened" << std::endl;`

Comment: I expect your file was never opened and the text message about opening successful was a lie.

Comment: but when I open the output file in the folder it printed everything up to "Task 1 - tuition Disocunt"? just not anything in my while statement so does this mean its not actually open or?

Comment: @Zamaire given the code you have shown, the ONLY way that can happen is if either `fin` is in an error state on the 1st check of `while (fin)`, or `semestersCompleted` is `< 3` inside the loop. So debug your code and figure out which condition is actually true.